# Spark java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I get the following error when I try to call 
I use python client for the spark.

```
lines = sc.textFile(hdfs://...)
lines.take(10)
```

I suspect that spark and hadoop versions might not be compatible. Here are the result of hadoop version:
    Hadoop 2.5.2
    Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r      cc72e9b000545b86b75a61f4835eb86d57bfafc0
    Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-14T23:45Z
    Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
    From source with checksum df7537a4faa4658983d397abf4514320
This command was run using /etc/hadoop-2.5.2/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.5.2.jar

I also have spark 1.3.1.

```
File "/etc/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1194, in take
    totalParts = self._jrdd.partitions().size()
File "/etc/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
File "/etc/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.partitions.
    : java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AppendRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.    ()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2556)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2566)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1412)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(ProxyGenerator.java:409)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(ProxyGenerator.java:306)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:610)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getProxy(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
```

I have been searching for the problem, some people refer to the version of protobuffer but I am not very familiar how to set it up correctly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

check the pom.xml where you compiled

search for protobuf version. It might solve the problem.

Or the problem might be something else as mentioned in this Jira thread.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7238

Comment: Thanks, What should be the command to build the spark? Do I need to specify the hadoop version and how?

Comment: If you have downloaded the package, this command will build spark and its example programs:                                                                   build/mvn -DskipTests clean package

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the py4j jar version that is needed for this hadoop version. Download that and place it in the lib folder of spark installed directory. And check bashrc for path reference. It will fix this error