# proto3, com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readStringRequireUtf8()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol Buffer(proto3) from my latest project. But I encounter below problem. An encoded message generated from python and I'm trying to decode it from Scala (I'm using SPARK). You can see the actual message from "value" and its length 227 as described in console.

The error field just typical string type field. I also have tried to decode string field as "UTF-8" but it is not worked.  It looks encode/decode problem. Are there some other guys who encounter similar problems?

### Console output

```
...

value: 
U
$a5a9c2bb-efd2-4ea3-ae0e-7479925a7807"kafka_producer.py*2016-12-18 10:37:25.075614*
data{"url": "some url 0", "title": "some title", "_id": "5815a37c43cfd44120e50538", "content": "some content", "tags": ["football"]}
value length: 227
Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readStringRequireUtf8()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.libero.messages.Messages$Event.<init>(Messages.java:160)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$Event.<init>(Messages.java:117)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$Event$1.parsePartialFrom(Messages.java:1564)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$Event$1.parsePartialFrom(Messages.java:1559)
at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:309)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$EventDataProduced.<init>(Messages.java:1742)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$EventDataProduced.<init>(Messages.java:1697)
at org.libero.messages.Messages$EventDataProduced$1.parsePartialFrom(Me

...
```

### Code fragments

```
 ....

 nonEmptyMsgs.foreachRDD { msgsRDD =>
      println("Trying to print each RDD: " + msgsRDD)
      println("Count: " + msgsRDD.count())
      val elems = msgsRDD.collect()
      println("Elems: " + elems)
      for (v <- elems) {
        println("key: " + v._1)
        println("value: " + v._2)
        println("value length: " + v._2.length())
        val bytes = new String(v._2).getBytes()
        val event = EventDataProduced.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFrom(bytes))
        println("event: " + event)
      }
    }

...
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? please check.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct version of the .jar file?

Comment: My version of protobuf-java jar is 3.1.0.

Answer (score 6):

[How can I use proto3 with Hadoop/Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487996/how-can-i-use-proto3-with-hadoop-spark)

as above link, i fixed it.

Just need to relocate the protobuffers and the VerifyError goes away:

```
      <relocations>
        <relocation>
          <pattern>com.google.protobuf</pattern>
          <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.protobuf</shadedPattern>
        </relocation>
      </relocations>
```

Comment: how to do this in Gradle. I'm getting the same exception but so far no luck with gradle.

Answer (score 2):

For those folks how use `gradle` and faced with the same problem like @Nowa and myself, here's the solution:
Add below lines into your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

shadowJar {
    baseName = "${jarName}"
    zip64 true
    // This is to avoid the version conflicts in between 
    relocate ('com.google.protobuf', 'otherplace.com.google.protobuf')
}
```