# proto2 with Spark cannot run

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, gradle, protocol-buffers

I've a proto file with syntax `proto2`

Also, I need to use Spark (2.0.2) and HBase. My project is built using Gradle.

Right now, when I run my Java code, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor.getOneofs()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1707)
    at com.google.protobuf.AnyProto.<clinit>(AnyProto.java:52)
    at com.google.protobuf.Any.getDescriptor(Any.java:129)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.buildWellKnownTypeParsers(JsonFormat.java:1100)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$ParserImpl.<clinit>(JsonFormat.java:1094)
    at com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat$Parser.merge(JsonFormat.java:277)
```

This stacktrace is very similar to the issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487996/how-can-i-use-proto3-with-hadoop-spark), but the resolution posted there didn't apply for me.

What I tried:

I changed

`compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '2.5.0'`

to

`compile group: 'org.spark-project.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '2.4.1-shaded'` as that link suggested, but still, the same error persisted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here's the solution:

`relocate` is the way to rescue.

In my main program, I've a build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':utils:hbasewrapper', configuration: 'shadow')
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'awesome-jar'
    zip64 true
    // This is to avoid the conflict between proto3 we are using and the proto2 hbase is using.
    relocate ('com.google.protobuf', 'importer.com.google.protobuf')
}
```

Then, I created another gradle package which has following build.gradle

```
group 'com.abc.hbasewrapper'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-client', version: '1.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.hbase', name: 'hbase-server', version: '1.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

shadowJar {
    baseName = 'hbasewrapper'
    version = null
    zip64 true
    relocate ('com.google.protobuf', 'hbasewrapper.com.google.protobuf')
    relocate ('io.netty', 'hbasewrapper.io.netty')
}
```

The root cause is due the HBase is referencing proto2 and my program is using proto3, thus causing this `NoSuchMethodError` error.
The solution is to use `relocate`, to relocate the `com.google.protobuf` to a different gradle project which sole purpose is to build the hbase jar files that has proto2.

Hope it helps other fellow programmers! ^ ^