# Error when generating tfrecord via MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, tensorflow, tfrecord, protobuf-java

I'm trying to use a MR job to generate TFRecord, but come across an error which I can't understand, it seems can't find a way to read the list?? It throws the following when I trying to build the Example which follows the hadoop example in tensorflow. Can anyone point out a way ? Thanks

```
2018-06-06 23:49:44,386 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor.getOneofs()Ljava/util/List;
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3$FieldAccessorTable.<init>(GeneratedMessageV3.java:1704)
at org.tensorflow.example.FeatureProtos.<clinit>(FeatureProtos.java:104)
at org.tensorflow.example.Feature.internalGetFieldAccessorTable(Feature.java:109)
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getAllFieldsMutable(GeneratedMessageV3.java:124)
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getAllFields(GeneratedMessageV3.java:200)
at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:272)
at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.access$400(TextFormat.java:248)
at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.print(TextFormat.java:71)
at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.printToString(TextFormat.java:118)
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.toString(AbstractMessage.java:106)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a JAVA library compatibity issue. Basically YARN loads a version of [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) (likely a 2.x) which is not compatible with the one you used to build up your JAR (probably a 3.x)

Check the YARN logs to identify the version being loaded, and rebuild your JAR with the same one.

Comment: But I have another job which can work. The only difference is the successful one does not have a reducer. But this one has. Is this related ? Thanks

Comment: Likely the class is loaded by reducer but the root cause is for sure a compatibility (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123603/proto2-with-spark-cannot-run )

Comment: Yep, I also checked some posts and go dipper into the logs. Thanks !